# Is it possible to build dynamic graphic content based on keyboard input with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I would like to build a web app to display an image of the finished product, a metal pin to be worn on a shirt, jacket, etc., in real time as the user enters the characters on their keyboard.

Parameters include:
1. The initials of the institution - 3 to 4 characters total
2. The name of the institution mascot - varied lengths
3. The icon for the mascot - pre-made art the user can select
4. The displayed pin would be dynamic in terms of size and shape based on selections 1-3

I know this can be done in Flash, but the development cost would be extensive there. Is there an existing JQuery build that might accommodate this in a more time efficient manner?

---

@David - I will be working with HTML5. The project is in layout so no coding has been done.

@NgM - Just spent the last half hour looking over the links that you put up. Thanks - that solves much. I feel comfortable pitching the concept to the client now.

Comment: And what have *you* tried already? What mark-up are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

You can tie into events on the controls in order to update the image.  Assuming the displayed pins are just a set of images you have stored somewhere, inside of the event you tie into you can easily do an image replace and change the size and shape etc.

These references should help get you started:

[jQuery Events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)

[Swap Image](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/jquery-image-swap-or-how-to-replace.html)

[Image Resize plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/image-resize)